# Json As Writeable Scala Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to take an `http` request and send it to another service. I want to use the json sent from the first `POST` and send it on to the next service. The problem I am having is turning the `POST` data as json and put it into a new `POST` but it is not Play's type `Writeable`.

Here is the code:

```
def postProxyParse(proxyUrl: String) = Action.async { request =>
    var url = buildUrl(request.uri)
    val data = request.body.asJson
    if(url ==""){
      badRequest(null, "Url Not matching proxy possibilities")
    }
    WS.url(url).post(data).map { response =>
       Ok(response.body)
    }
}
```

The Error I am getting is `Cannot write an instance of Option[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[Option[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]]`

Comment: Can you give us the exact error you get?

Comment: Your code as written is not producing that error. Are you sure you didn't write `Ok(data)` or `Ok(response.body.asJson)`?

Comment: @wingedsubmariner You're right my bad If you look now the error is being thrown at the post when I am trying to pass the data to the new service

Comment: Try `val data = request.body.asJson.getOrElse(badRequest(null, "Bad JSON"))`.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner I added what ended up working... not sure if you would be interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi so the point of this was to create a proxy service to redirect post requests with a specific url. The answer to this problem is:

```
  def postProxyParse(proxyUrl: String) = Action.async { request =>
val url = buildUrl(request.uri)
var data = Json.parse(request.body.asText.get);
if(url ==""){
  badRequest(null, "Url Not matching proxy possibilities")
}
WS.url(url).withHeaders(  "Accept" -> "application/json",
  "Cookie" -> ("sessionId=" + request.cookies.apply("sessionId").value)).post(data).map { response =>
  Ok(data)
}
}
```

The full code for a scala proxy service is [here](https://github.com/gdh56/scalaPlayProxy)